# Clustering a list of restaurant dishes

Tags: clustering, natural-language, partitioning

If I have a large list of restaurant dishes that all have the same cuisine... (Pulled Pork, BBQ chicken, 1/2 Ribs, Pork Sliders, Slow Smoked Pork, Full Chicken Special....)

What would be a good approach to clustering these dishes such that "Pulled Pork" and "Slow Smoked Pork" and "Pork Slider" all end up in the same cluster.

Once challenge I'm running into is identifying that "Pork" is an important word and dishes with "Pork" in it should be clustered, meanwhile recognizing that "Pulled Chicken", "Pulled Pork", and "Pulled Beef" are completely different, despite the fact that "Pulled" appears in all the terms.

Thanks

Comment: Do you already know what you want the final clusters to be? Usually, "clustering" refers to cases where you don't know which items (dishes) should go together & are trying to find out. If you already know which you want to go together, you could try classification methods.

Comment: Not sure what your approach is to structuring the data -- or your modeling methods (multinomial perhaps?)...so just a suggestion: have you considered coding these separately? You could have factor substance = factor(c('Pork','Chicken','Beef')) and method = factor(c('Pulled','BBQ','Smoked')).  You might be able to find clusters within clusters.  more information or a data sample would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a clustering problem.
No algorithm will be able to do this automatically.

You need to provide the data that "pork" is important and "grilled" is not.